# Modular forms question

Tags: number-theory

Can someone enlighten me with the question in the next page:
http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?p=3208664#post3208664

I am asked to find all the modular forms with weight $k$ which don't have zeros on the upper half plane.

Comment: Would you mind retyping the question here?

Comment: I am asked to find all the modular forms with weight k which don't have zeros on the upper half plane.

Answer (score 4):

The discriminant cusp form $\Delta$ is such a modular form, and its weight is twelve. It has a simple zero at infinity and no other zeroes. Suppose *f* is any modular form without zeroes in *H*. If *f* has a zero of order *k* at infinity, then $f/\Delta^k$ is a modular form with no zeroes or poles so it is constant. In particular the weight of *f* is $12k$.

Comment: Thanks Dan, is that all the modular forms there are?

Comment: Wait a minute the weight of $\delta$ is 12 so the weight of $\delta ^k $ is 12k, and the weight of $\frac{f}{\delta^k}$ should be -12k, right?

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist: Dan proves (very succinctly) that the only modular forms with no zeros on the upper half plane are $c \Delta^k$ where c is any constant.  (If such a modular form f has weight 12k, then dividing f by $\Delta^k$ gives you a modular form of weight 0, so it must be a constant. $f/\Delta^k=c$, so $f=c\Delta^k$.)